# Getting Birthdays Regardless The Year

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit confuse on my query like getting all birthdays within a date range. I have my scenario here,

```
date_from = "2014-12-01" date_to = "2015-01-30"
```

Another scenario is

```
date_from = "2015-02-01" date_to = "2015-03-31"
```

Comment: you can use union all to get combined data from both of query in a single query

Comment: hi Jordan, i already updated by post sorry for the wrong info. But i just want to get all birthdays regardless of the year. We all know that the birthday is recurring so it doesn't mind if its 1990's or 2000's.

Comment: I've updated my answer as your requirement, let me know if it's working for you or not

Comment: What about those people born 31st January?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (date_column BETWEEN '2014-12-01 AND '2015-01-30' ) OR ( date_column BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-03-31')
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '12-01' AND '12-31'
OR DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '12-30'
OR DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '02-01' AND '03-31'
```

Comment: I updated my post, there's something wrong in it, i just want to get all those birthdays but regardless of year. Because birthdays are recurring then if we will include the year it won't work.

Comment: Right! So tell me required month range, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: `BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-01', '%m-%d')`, why bother taking the year into the where just to remove it? :p

Comment: AND (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2014-12-01', '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-30', '%m-%d'))  I tried this one but there's no output.. i don't know why?

Comment: You have to write like this. `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '12-01' AND '12-31'
OR DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '01-30'`

Comment: Since we are not considering year factor here, so first we have to query `12-01' AND '12-31'` and then `'01-01' AND '01-30'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (date>='2014-12-01' AND date<='2015-01-30') OR (date>='2015-02-01' AND date<='2015-03-31')
```

Comment: You can use `between`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from `table` where `birthday` between '2014-12-01' and '2015-01-30'
```

or

```
select * from `table` where `birthday` >= '2014-12-01' and `birthday` <= '2015-01-30'
```

OK I understand. Try this

```
select * from `table` where substr(`birthday`,6) between '12-01' and '01-30'
```

Comment: Hi Konstantinos, i just want to display all dec 1 to january 30 birthdays.. regardless the year

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-01-30' 
union
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-03-31';
```

Comment: Hi Assen, i already tried this one
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (date_column BETWEEN '2014-12-01 AND '2015-01-30' )

but it will display the birthdays on year 2014 and 2015.. i want to display all regardless of the year. So its like from dec 12 - jan 30 birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
select * from `table` where (`birthday` between '2014-12-01' and '2015-01-30') or
(`birthday` >= '2014-12-01' and `birthday` <= '2015-01-30')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "01-01" AND "01-30"
OR DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "12-01" AND "12-31"
OR DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "02-01" AND "03-31"
```

This way the year in your date will be ignored, you just have to define the ranges correctly. (beginning of december to end of december, not into january; then  next beginning in january)

As an example to build the query in php:

```
$from = "2015-12-01";
$to = "2016-01-31";

if(substr($from, 0, 4) < substr($to, 0, 4)){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 
                WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "' . substr($from, 5) . '" AND "12-31" 
                OR DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "01-01" AND "' . substr($to, 5) . '"';
}else{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 
                WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "' . substr($from, 5) . '" AND "' . substr($to, 5) . '"';
}
var_dump($query);
exit;
```

Of yourse you have to add the usual security methods and add checks for validity of the data.

Comment: Hi Philip, can you enhance this code?

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "01-01" AND "01-30"
OR DATE_FORMAT(`yourField`,"%m-%d") BETWEEN "12-01" AND "12-31"

i only have 2 date picker value for the range.. thanks..  i think my query is closer to this one.

Comment: Then you will have to check if the chosen daterange  switches from one year into the other and then build your query accordingly. As in the example, if you have a range from december into january you need two between statemnts, for the december of the first year and for the january. The other case, from like february to march/october/december would be no problem

Comment: added some php as example